# C++ match the input with data in the text file, and if it match only display that data

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a problem with the following section.
This particular part should do the following:
List all modules taught by selected lecturer

I'm struggling with part of match the input from the user with data in the text file, and only display that list of module taught by the selected lecturer.

I have text file called: Taught.txt and the content of the text file is of the following:

```
IS1S01  AW 
IS1S02  MG 
SE2S552 BM 
CS2S504 BM 
CS3S08  SL 
MS3S28  DJ
CS1S03  EM 
BE1S01  SJ 
BE2S01  SH 
SS1S02  AB 
SE1S02  AW
```

The below section is code I have done so far.

```
void listofmodulebylecturer()
{
    std::string Lecturer;
    std::string Module;

    // Display message asking for the user input
    std::cout << "\nList all modules taught by selected lecturers." << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Enter your preferred lecturers." << std::endl;

    // Read in from the user input
    std::cin >> Lecturer;

    // Read from text file and Display list of modules taught by the selected lecturer

    std::ifstream infile;

    // infile.open("Lecturer");
    infile.open("Taught.txt");

    if (!infile)
    {
        std::cout << "List is empty" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nList of Modules:" << std::endl;

        while(!infile.eof())
        {
            getline(infile,Module);

            std::cout << Module << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "End of list\n" << std::endl;
    }

    infile.close();         // close the text file  
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

I was thinking of using

```
if (........)
{
}
else
```

I wondering if that can work?

Comment: Do **not** use `while (!infile.eof())`. Use `while (getline(infile, Module))` instead. Looks like a `std::multimap` would be the perfect tool, though.

Comment: @user addition to chris. if will work fine. Just comapre your input string with line scanned from file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `infile.eof()` cannot work reliable for the purpose you want to use it for. You should read two words and print the first word if the second word matches the expected. Reading the words would look something like this:

```
for (std::string module, teacher; infile >> module >> teacher; ) {
    // check if the teacher is the correct one and, if so, print the module
}
```

... and, yes, an `if` statement works for this.

Answer (score 0):

Since each line contains only two strings, I wouldn't use `getline()` but this:

```
std::string course, teacher;

while (infile) {
    infile >> course >> teacher;
    if (infile) { // strings read correctly
        if (teacher == Lecturere) {
         ...
        }
    }
}
```